# asp mvc RedirectToAction not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have checked the solutions in the other links, but nothign seems to work for me.

I have the following;

```
 [HttpPost]        
    public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateDisclaimers(FinanceConfirmViewModel fcvm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           ... processing all works
            return RedirectToAction("Index", enquiryId );    
        }
     }

   [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index(int? enquiryId)
    {
     .....
    }
```

but when the UpdateDisclaimers Action is run and succeeds, the browser returns a 404

```
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) 
could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please 
review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /Recommended
```

(Recommended is the Controller.)

I can access the Controler index via an Action Link elsewhere and it works.
the Index is async, so I have made UpdateDisclaimers Async as suggested in another solution.

So I'm stumped. Any ideas?

edit: marked the answer below as correct. Solution is in the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have

```
public ActionResult Index(int enquiryId)
{
// Code
}
```

on the same controller

=> Final repsonse: because of POST,

```
return Index(enquiryId);
```

Comment: they are both on the same controller, sorry if that was not apparent.

Comment: Thanks, that was it, I just needed the return statement. Had to be somethign simple :-)

Comment: @Matt this is because of your post, you cannot redirect to a POST. GET yeah but not post.